# Is a Lebesgue measurable subset a null set if each compact subset is a nullset?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $A \subset \Bbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable.($m$ is Lebesgue measure) and for every compact $K \subset A$, $m(K)=0$; is it true that $m(A)=0$?

Comment: Have you heard the phrase ["inner regular"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_regular_measure)?

Comment: No.you mean m(A)=0?could you explain it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $m(A) = 0$, given your hypothesis. This is a direct consequence of the inner regularity of Lebesgue measure, as David pointed out, which states that
$$
  m(A) = \sup\{ m(K) : K \subset A, K \textrm{ compact} \}.
$$

Comment: @JohnMa: Er, I'm pretty sure it holds even when $m(A) = \infty$.  If you believe it holds for all sets with finite measure, then suppose $m(A) = \infty$ and for each $n$ choose compact $K_n \subset A \cap [-n,n]$ with $m(K_n) \ge m(A \cap [-n,n]) - 1$.  Since by countable additivity $m(A \cap [-n,n]) \to m(A) = \infty$ we have $m(K_n) \to \infty$ as well.